# How do I delete rows which have the same entries in both columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame (with 500 observations) of 2 columns which look like this:

```
1   118_o_m_n_a.jpg 118_o_m_a_a.jpg
2   122_m_f_n_a.jpg 122_m_f_n_a.jpg
3   152_y_f_n_a.jpg 152_y_f_n_a.jpg
4   160_y_m_h_a.jpg 160_y_m_n_a.jpg
5   083_o_m_a_a.jpg 083_o_m_s_a.jpg
6   015_o_m_n_a.jpg 015_o_m_h_a.jpg
7   058_m_m_n_a.jpg 058_m_m_n_a.jpg
```

I want to delete the rows which has same entries in column 1 and 2 (rows 2,3,7 in this case). Now I tried to "unique" function but it somehow didn't work, or I couldn't do it properly.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your condition in `[` and then assign result back to original data.frame. Here your condition is `df[, 1] != df[, 2]`. By not specifying any column after `,` you are selecting all columns.

```
df
##                V1              V2
## 1 118_o_m_n_a.jpg 118_o_m_a_a.jpg
## 2 122_m_f_n_a.jpg 122_m_f_n_a.jpg
## 3 152_y_f_n_a.jpg 152_y_f_n_a.jpg
## 4 160_y_m_h_a.jpg 160_y_m_n_a.jpg
## 5 083_o_m_a_a.jpg 083_o_m_s_a.jpg
## 6 015_o_m_n_a.jpg 015_o_m_h_a.jpg
## 7 058_m_m_n_a.jpg 058_m_m_n_a.jpg

df <- df[df[, 1] != df[, 2], ]
df
##                V1              V2
## 1 118_o_m_n_a.jpg 118_o_m_a_a.jpg
## 4 160_y_m_h_a.jpg 160_y_m_n_a.jpg
## 5 083_o_m_a_a.jpg 083_o_m_s_a.jpg
## 6 015_o_m_n_a.jpg 015_o_m_h_a.jpg
```